# Salesforce debug logs: hide managed package lines

Tags: debugging, salesforce, apex-code, apex

When I try to debug my work using the debug logs on Salesforce, I endup with hundreds of lines like this - see below, which overflow my debug logs capacity and ending up with me not able to see the non managed package line, is there a way to get rid or filter the managed package lines on the debug logs, for reference here is a glimpse of how they look like:

I was not able to create a filter on the debug logs to filter on the lines below, any thought ? thanks

20:42:50.42 (237707811)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (237726121)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (237752484)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (237770719)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (237893145)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (237911714)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (237938083)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (237956602)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (238060177)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (238078324)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (238119869)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (238140176)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (238302023)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (238329651)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE
20:42:50.42 (238380411)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|nFORCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Change Debug Level you can change the log shown in the Developer console's log timeline. Go to add/change under DebugLevel Action and set a lower level on the information saved, in your case as suggested above, you have to set to INFO (or lower), alternatively you can create a layer for your job/class  only by clicking Add-->yourclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your log levels from FINE to INFO it would not show managed packages log info for the specific logs you are interested it that should fix the issue for you